# Binding and changing mapped objects in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am creating a spreadsheet-type app with AngularJS and it takes a CSV file, parses it, filters it with some regular expressions, and then outputs the data. However, the data is color-coded.

The initial coloring is done by combing through an array of all the data, and finding the elements that match a 'red' regular expression or a 'blue' one. If it matches, it is pushed into either a 'red' or 'blue' array. A function then runs alongside the creation of the spreadsheet, and if the cell element is in either 'red' or 'blue', the function returns 'red' or 'blue' which colors the cell its respective color with the CSS. All other cells are green by default.

That coloring function is mapped to the data that is written on screen in the spreadsheet. So an example of a value would look like this if written to the browser:
`{'content':"Red Box", 'color':"red"}`

I have my input tags for the spreadsheet bound to the content that goes in them. However, I can't seem to change the color with the content. I want to know how to change the color (via a function), since I need to run regular expressions on the user's input to know what color to change the box. Below you'll see that the color is actually mapped to the output of the `makeColor` function. I *dont't* need to use that function when the data is changed. I plan on making different functions for that.

Here is some code:

```
<script>
...
sheet= function($scope, $parse){
    $scope.columns = headers;
    $scope.rows = allData.length;
    $scope.cells = {};
    $scope.values = allData.map(function(c,row){
        return c.map(function(data){
            return {
                content: data,
                color: makeColors(data)
            };
        });
    });

    $scope.change = function(data){
        console.log("A change was made!");
    };
};
</script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="sheet">
    <table>
        <tr class="column-label">
            <td ng-repeat="column in columns">{{column}}</td>
        <tr ng-repeat="value in values">
            <td class="row-label" ng-repeat="data in value">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="inputValue"  ng-model="data.content" class="{{data.color}}"
                     ng-change="change(this.value)" ng-change="data.color='red'" colorize="colorize">
                </div>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

So perhaps a more generic question would be better:

With an object in the `$scope` that is mapped to multiple things, how could I change or access those multiple things on change from the `ng-change` method for `input` tags?